# How to copy Input Text Value into Dynamic Text that is in a MovieClip1 Inside a MovieClip2

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Current my code is as such

```
setcustomlocation.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,customlocation2);

function customlocation2(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    locationinput.text = FlashingWon.Won1.name.text;
}
```

I'm trying to make it such that it would copy the input text field values into a dynamic text. However, it throws up the error that

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
>       at main/customlocation2()[main::frame1:9]

Which can I only assume that it is not able to communicate with the dynamic text field in the movieclip within another movieclip.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can be 100% sure that it CAN communicate with the dynamic TextField in the MovieClip.

From you description I understand that you wish to copy from input into dynamic. But from your code I see that you take from the dynamic into the input, please check that out:

```
// This will copy in such a way: input <= wonText 
locationinput.text = FlashingWon.Won1.name.text;

// This will copy from input
FlashingWon.Won1.name.text = locationinput.text;
```

Anyhow, the error that you get has nothing to do with this, it's rather like you already noticed, that one of your TextField is not *'found'*. For this I recommend you a best practice: To create instances of the objects you want to use and populate them from the stage through the getChildByName method. This way you will promptly now (specially if you do this on construction or init) if you had any misspelling or miss structure on the childs you want to get.

like so:

```
var inputText: TextField;
var dynoText: TextField;
```

In your Constructor or else where at a soon level, give to your vars the proper value:

```
inputText = getChildByName('locationinput') as TextField;
dynoText = FlashingWon.Won1.getChildByName('name') as TextField;
```

This way you will soon enough know if one of this 2 textFields were not found under the object you give, and you have only one place to miss spell it. Also you will get code completion on your TextFields.

Finally the copy text part:

```
dynoText.text = inputText.text;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm not too sure where I should place the codes. Do I place them inside the movie clip or on the root stage?

Also, there seems to be a conflict between the 2 TextField

Comment: Ok, I was going from the premise that you were coding on the root stage. Take in count that depending on where your code is, the address to localize the TextFields might be different.

The code I wrote though is thought to be on the root stage and only if the input text is also on Stage level. Else you need to populate the input with a different address:

    `inputText = inpuTextParentAtTheRoot.getChildByName('locationinput') as TextField;`

Comment: Yes I am coding on the root stage. However if I define both var inputText and dynoText as Textfield there is a conflict.

Also, I am really not sure how this would help me determine which textfields are not found.

Comment: I tried this for testing
`var dynoText = FlashingWon.Won1('name') as TextField;


setlocationrundlest.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,setlocation2);

function setlocation2(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    dynoText.text = "TESTING";
}`

Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at App_Beta_3_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()[App_Beta_3_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:6]

Comment: you are missing the `getChildByName` method: `var dynoText = FlashingWon.Won1.getChildByName('name') as TextField;`

It helps cause you only have one place where you do the critical mistake of having typos or wrong locations of your field. Else if you continue referencing it always `FlashingWon.Won1.name` the code editor wont find an error if you later on type `FlashingWon.Won1.nAme` instead but on compile time and only if you manually test the method where that error is you will have a bug.

Comment: I'm still having problems copying the text into the Dynamic Test inside a MovieClip in another Movie Clip

Comment: oh wait. I think i know what is wrong, my FlashingWon.Won1.name is in a different frame. It is in frame 12.

Comment: Nope, now I am at a dilema on how to implement the getchildbyname seeing that the movie clip hasn't been loaded on the timeline

Comment: well you should then listen to the event dispatched when it's added to the Stage. `FlashingWon.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, handle_Added);` and then in your new function handle_Added when it's already on your stage you can get the child from it. More info about event dispatching on the official [asdocs of adobe for AS3](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html)

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I only have a rudimentary knowledge of AS3, I only knew the basics about AS2 and now AS3 has changed so much. If it is not too much hassle, could you give me an example code?

Comment: It's dificult to give you an example code without really knowing what you have on the stage and if you want things to be in different frames or if they are on the same. 

Without knowing your exact needs and condition I would need to write a book to be sure that I'm solving your issue. Try giving more info about the error that you are having right now and describing more your stage. I would also recommend you to have the root scene with just one timeline, while having movieclips added onto it.

Comment: I have created an example of what I am trying to achieve.
[link](http://db.tt/1VIcrIgl)

Im trying to have a user defined text input field echoing the values into a dynamic text field from within 2 layers of movie clips on another frame.

Comment: Ok, I'll check it out and come back to you tomorrow or monday.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, sorry for the delay, I was out on holidays.
I have opened your example and can see where the problems are:

1) You are trying to reach the `FlashingWon` when initiating the dynoText on the FIRST frame like so `var dynoText = FlashingWon.Won1.getChildByName('name_txt');` BUT the FlashingWon element is ONLY available on the FIFTH frame. Meaning that you cannot refer to it quite yet, unless you add it on the first frame and make in invisible till the fifth frame. (You can make it visible in the `goto1` function if you wish after the `goToAndStop(5)` line)

2) You called the TextField on the `Won1` element  'name' which is a restricted sting in AS3, so change it to name_txt or label if you wish and it will work.

Let me know how it worked.